# Node.js, SQLite3, and Express - potential memory leak on POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, v8, node-memwatch

I'm relatively new to node.js, and I've been tasked with writing a simple message queue app - basically, the app will receive a post containing some message data and the client's mac address, which we decode and then insert into a sqlite database, to be posted later by a separate process.

Everything works fine, but we're experiencing what may be a memory leak. Using the memwatch module, I've narrowed the leak down to our code handling incoming posts, which I've included below:

```
app.route('*')
    .post(function(req, res){
    var mac = decodeURI(unescape(req.param('mac').replace(/\+/g, "%20")));
    var data = decodeURI(unescape(req.param('data').replace(/\+/g, "%20")));    
    req = null;

    db.run("INSERT INTO queue (mac, data) VALUES (?,?)", [mac, data], function(er){
        if(er) {
            res.writeHead(500, "Insert to queue failed", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end();
        }
        res = null;
        mac = null;
        data = null;
    });
})
```

I'm unable to find anything in here that looks incorrect, but when we post 10000 requests to the app we almost always trigger a memory leak event in memwatch. I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction here: are we simply misinterpreting memwatch, or is there a leak here I'm missing somehow? As I understand it memwatch considers heap growth over 5 or more V8 garbage collection attempts consecutively to be a leak - it seems possible that with 10000 posts at once like this that that sort of heap growth would be expected, but I haven't yet found a definitive answer and need to rule it out. Any help, even if you just point me in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anyone? We're particularly worried about this one - the goal of this message queue is basically to reduce our required server resources and, obviously, our server bills. We can't have it leaking memory as it basically defeats the purpose of the queue entirely.